# Is there a way in C# to call a method just once like in the jQuery "one" method?

Tags: c#

I wish to know if there is a way to execute code in C# just once, like "one" in jquery:

$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});

What I would like to do is the following:

```
public void foo(){
  Console.Write("hello");
}
```

then

```
foo();
foo();
foo();
```

and the output result must be

```
hello
```

I´m looking for a library and not just using flags attributes.

Comment: Generally, the trick is to not call it in the first place. What problem are you trying to solve? What context will this be used in? Is `foo()` an event listener? Doing this will violate the expectations of whoever else uses the function

Comment: Why so keen on using a library? Seems like overkill for something that would be easily solved with the 'flag-based' solution.

Comment: The method could set a static variable that indicates it has already been called.

Comment: FYI a method that has the same effect when called twice as when called once is called an "idempotent" method. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/10/26/483900.aspx) Usually what you do is set a flag that indicates whether the method has been called already or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't imagine why do something like that, but if you really do it and if you want it universal for any method, you can do this:

```
void Main() {
    var myFoo = callOnlyOnce(foo);
    myFoo();
    myFoo();
    myFoo();

   var myBar = callOnlyOnce(bar);
   myBar();
   myBar();
   myBar();
}

void foo(){
  Console.Write("hello");
}
void bar() { Console.Write("world"); }


Action callOnlyOnce(Action action){
    var context = new ContextCallOnlyOnce();
    Action ret = ()=>{
        if(false == context.AlreadyCalled){
            action();
            context.AlreadyCalled = true;
        }
    };

    return ret;
}
class ContextCallOnlyOnce{
    public bool AlreadyCalled;
}
```

Comment: I think the idea is that the logging within foo() is called only once, but this is still a clever solution.  It creates the necessary context implicitly as part of the wrapper method and captures it in a closure, which is a nice way of encapsulating it.  Still, my guess is this is not sufficient for the real problem the OP needs to solve, as very rarely is the issue that you only want to log once in the entire life of the program.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Mostly I agree with you. However I don't like global variables, so I think this solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 17):

The jQuery example is an event handler, and once the event handler has been called it is removed from the element. The equivalent in C# for (eg.) an button click event would be

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(MyEventHandler)

void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Console.Write("hello");
  ((Button)sender).Click -= new EventHandler(MyEventHandler);
}
```

In this way, only the first click of the button would yield the Console Write.

Comment: +1 Removed my answer since this one provides the example. This is the equivalent of the jquery example.

Comment: "In this way, only the first click of the button would yield the Console Write." - That is not completely true. If he has multi-threaded code or code that invoked in any number of ad-hoc ways and that can result more then 1 invoke, before handler is removed. Adding `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` before method declaration, would be 1 way to fix this.

Comment: #smoothWithoutABooleanFlag  I like this !

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old news... but here is a Functional approach to the question that someone might find useful:

```
    public static Action<T> Once<T>(Action<T> action )
    {
        return (arg) =>
        {
            action?.Invoke(arg);
            action = null;
        };
    }
```

Then you can generate a function that will only do the meat of the work one time:

```
    var writeNumberToConsole = Once<int>( Console.WriteLine );
    writeNumberToConsole(1); // "1"
    writeNumberToConsole(2); -> //nothing
    writeNumberToConsole(3); -> //nothing
```

Comment: I really like this. A null reference check is fast.

Answer (score 7):

Why do you want a library when you could just do something like this:

```
private bool wasExecuted = false;

public void foo(){
  if (!wasExecuted) {
     Console.Write("hello");
     wasExecuted = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private bool _fooExecuted = false;

public void foo(){
  if (_fooExecuted)
     return;

  _fooExecuted = true;

  Console.Write("hello");
}
```

Comment: Yeap, but he explicitely asked not to use flags.

Comment: @Ernesto: Yeap, but he explicitely asked for a library that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ernesto: he said "flags attributes"... i'm not using any attributes.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer, that's absolutely true. @HABJAN, yeap, but I don't know if he actually meant something with attributes. Other than the question been a bit too explicit about what he want's, this answer is a completely right way to solve that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to find a library for this. This required behavior is very rare, at best. The easiest way to accomplish this would just be to have a static flag variable like so:

```
static bool hasRun = false;
public void doSomething {
    if (hasRun) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not so rare, I think; it's very common to have some logging functionality, but to want to suppress repeated logging if the condition recurs (such as a connection lost detected in a polling loop, for instance; you don't want to log every reconnect attempt.)  This is a bit trickier than simply only logging it once, however, as you need a way to 'reset' and allow logging again once you've successfully connected.

Comment: @Dan: I can see where you're coming from, but at the same time *I* would want every bit of information I could get if I was hunting down a bug using those logs.

Comment: Granted, that's true, but I've run into some really nasty boundary cases with repeated logging of a persistent condition.  In one case, the application was actually logging failing camera images and filled up the drive, causing the system to hard-crash.  It's a general problem that can occur in any type of 'automatic retry' scenario.  Even in less severe cases, it can often make the log harder to read.

Comment: The problem with the static variable is,for instance, if this is a web app, and the method is used in different pages, the only one page will get the code executed.

Comment: This is pretty common. I often have an initialization function that I can't put into the constructor because it requires data that hasn't yet been set.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean only once in the entire execution of the program or will you ever have a reset criteria that allows it to be displayed again?  In either case, I recommend creating a wrapper class that you instantiate as a field with an embedded bool flag for each particular line you want to 'only once' display.  If the string is known to be fixed (no parameters that alter it), you can also use a central service class that keeps a set of strings that have already been printed.  The issue with this is that you can't log the same string from multiple locations.

One common general solution is an 'alarm manager', though I haven't seen a standardized library for this.  It comes up frequently in my industry, however, as industrial machinery can enter a persistent alarm state and you want to log transitions into the alarm state, but not continually log that you're still in the alarm state.  The solutions I've used/seen usually create a unique alarm code for each condition, with a 'set' and 'clear' notion, often with operator intervention required to acknowledge and finally clear the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Uses stack trace and stack frame to get the file, method and line number of each call to Once() and saves that in a list.  By using the line number it keeps each usage of Once() unique.

Is fairly quick - got 400 executions in around 50ms on my old Dell 9020.

The thing I like best is there are no variables or declarations to make when using the function.  Just add it into the "if" statement and go.

Use the method like so:

```
if (Fun.Once())
{
    //Do stuff once 
}
```

Add this class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

    public class Fun
        {
            private static List<string> CallOnceList = new List<string>();
    
        public static bool Once()  
        {
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
            StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);
            string Caller=sf.GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName + "." + sf.GetMethod().Name + "." + sf.GetFileLineNumber();
            if (CallOnceList.IndexOf(Caller) < 0)
            {
                CallOnceList.Add(Caller);
                return true; 
            }else{
                return false; 
            }
        }
    
    }
```