# Listen for bool value to change on loop, then call method only once

Tags: c#, events, boolean

Is there any way to listen for a bool-value change then cal a method only once?

I'm working on project where I need to constantly monitor a variable that's a bool, and depending on if it's a TRUE or FALSE call a diffrent method.

I'm currently using an if-statment, which calls each method on loop when my variable is TRUE/FALSE.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bool property

```
private bool boolValue;
public bool BoolValue
{
 get { return boolValue; }
 set { 
     boolValue = value;
     if(value) { TrueMethod(); } 
     else { FalseMethod(); }

     }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from calling `TrueMethod();` if value is already set to `true`? Because I'm running a timer which keeps checking if a variable in another system is `true` or `false`, and then assigning a local variable with `true` or `false`

Comment: See this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597729/execution-of-code-just-once-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PropertyChanged event to have loosly coupling.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification