# How to tell if a sign in is completed using Sharp Browser?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I’ve created a password manager using Sharp Browser for signing into websites. Sign in is fully automatic on most websites on others copy and paste from textboxes on the browser form works.
The fully automatic sign in causes a problem when signing out on some sites, because they take you back to the sign in page creating an endless loop.

Knowing if the website was signed in, the textboxes can then be cleared thus stopping any potential resign in.

How do I check if a website is signed in?

I’m using the following for signing in.

Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById(‘username’).value=" + ''' + txtUserName + ''');
Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById(‘password’).value=" + ''' + txtPassword + ''');
Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById(‘sumit’).click();");

Comment: To my knowledge there is no universal are you logged in flag for a website. Perhaps you can get some inspiration from some of the open source chrome password manager extensions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I'll put that on the to do list and just stop the auto click for the problem websites for now,

Comment: I decided to use a once only function as HABJAN shows on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597729/is-there-a-way-in-c-sharp-to-call-a-method-just-once-like-in-the-jquery-one-me .